Visual Studio 2022 and Crystal Reports
I am rewriting a Visual Studio application where the Target Framework is net.NET 8 8.0-windows.  My original application has many Crystal reports that I want to re-use.  Problem is the Crystal Reports viewer requires .NET Framework 4.7.2.
Has anyone cracked this issue.
Tried .NET 8 Master project and .NET Framework 4.7.2 Reporting project in the same solution.   The Master project being dependant on the Reporting project (Crystal Reports).  This publishes OK but errors when a Form in the Crystal Reports application is called.

SAP Runtime works with .NET Framework. You cannot use it with .NET Core or .NET
